# Onedrive filePath is not working in Postman

Tags: php, api, post, postman, onedrive

Actually i am working on postman and i want to get the response.We can import the file into powerbi and this will return the id as response.This is working on only the file been uploaded.

Apparently I am trying to get the imported id in **Power BI**(api.powerbi.com) using postman.In the Request Body i given filePath of oneDrive but error occurs.Please help me.

[See the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXDLL.png)

i referred this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243840.aspx

i have passed all the parameters with **POST** method and also headers.

Comment: I am Getting 500 internal server error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you show us your error and there are 1000 of possibilities for that error. I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Comment: ok.Thank you @Teocci

Comment: please click the link and see my error (See the error)

Comment: As I told you there many ways for that error show us some code to know what is causing that error.

Comment: There is no program in postman.This is the Google Chrome app for interacting with HTTP APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.That was the authorization problem in Header.
And also i removed the key of oneDrive file path.
Thanks stack Overflow.